# JS - Nothing to repeat In match function

Tags: javascript

The error is simple. In JS I  try to do somtehing to similar a preg_match in PHP. I found match function. I use this function to compare a value with strings elements. If found something return true, else return false.

I tried this

```
  var sim_action = $(this);            
  if(sim_action.data("phone").toString().match("/^(+34|0034|34)+([67]){8})$/")){
```

But return this error.

> Invalid regular expression: //^(+34|0034|34)+([67]){8})$//: Nothing
>   to repeat

So the question is. How can i add this string in JS match function?

Comment: It's because `+` means "the previous character or group, repeated 1 or more times" - and you have nothing preceding it. If you meant to match a literal `+` character, escape it with a backslash: `\+`

Comment: You also have an unmatched parenthesis at the end

Comment: You need to escape the metacharacters like `+` and `()` with `\ ` https://regex101.com/r/r2IqKM/1. Currently it's not clear which are capturing groups and which are literal parenthesis. Can you share some sample phone numbers you're trying to match?

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the `+` characters with a backslash: `/^(\+34|0034|34)\+([67]){8})$/`. You also have a closing bracket which doesn't have a matching opening bracket.

Comment: That is still not a valid regex

Comment: If you remove the last `)` it is. Its likely not what OP wants but they didn't provide any  information on what it's meant to actually do.

Comment: Invalid regular expression: //^(+34|0034|34)+([67]){8}$//: Nothing to repeat

Comment: `/^(\+34|0034|34)\+([67]){8}$/` should be valid. Not sure if it matches what you want though. Provide some examples of what should and shouldn't match.

Comment: if(!sim_action.data("phone").toString().match("/^(\+34|0034|34)\+([67]){8}$/")){
                    console.log("enter");
                    } return nothing to repeat. I try to check is phone is a spanish phone or not.

Comment: What do you actually want the expression to match? Can you edit your question with some examples that should match and others that you don't want to match.

Answer (score 0):

`+` and `()` are metacharacters and if you want to refer to the literal, you need to escape them with a `\`. Here's a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/r2IqKM/1) which highlights the errors with your regex

As for the regex, from wikipedia, I gather that spanish phone numbers have the format `+34(6|7)xxxxxxxx`

You can use this regex: `/^(\+34|0034|34)[67]\d{8}$/`

If you just want to check if the regex passes , you can use `regex.test(<stringToBeTested>)`

```js
const regex = /^(\+34|0034|34)[67]\d{8}$/
const phone = "+34712345673";

if (regex.test(phone))
  console.log("Valid phone number")
  
const phoneNumbers = ["+34712345673", "0034612345673", "+34812345673"]
phoneNumbers.forEach(p => console.log(regex.test(p)))
```